# How to test handling of TCP write timeout?

Tags: linux, unit-testing, testing, network-programming

I have written an application that reads from and writes to a tcp socket.

Suppose the ethernet cable is unplugged after the application sends a message but before the TCP-level `ACK` response. An exception will thrown in my application.

**How can I test the exception handling without physically unplugging the cable?**

I'm using an application-level protocol that does not implement acknowledgments of its own.

I'm on windows but am open to solutions involving linux as well.

Comment: [Tylertreat | Comcast GitHub](https://github.com/tylertreat/comcast): Simulating shitty network connections so you can build better systems. It is a BSD, OS X and Linux solution using the firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Establish a TCP connection with a peer in a virtual machine, then kill the virtual machine with `kill -KILL <pid>`. Check in Wireshark that killing the virtual machine doesn't cause it to emit `RST` packet (because unplugging the cable doesn't).